# new ImmutableMap.Builder() vs ImmutableMap.builder()

Tags: java, dictionary, builder

[image]

```
private static final Map<String, String> LOCALE_FOLDER_MAP = new ImmutableMap.Builder()
        .put("a", "b")
        .build();

private static final Map<String, String> LOCALE_FOLDER_MAPP = ImmutableMap.builder()
        .put("a", "b")
        .build();
```

It is strange `ImmutableMap.builder()` returns `new ImmutableMap.Builder();`. After replacing the original code using the return statement, the above two code segments should be equivalent.

But it does not, which confuses me.

Does anyone have explanations?

The error message is

> Required type: Map <String, String>. Provided: ImmutableMap<Object,
> Object>

Comment: Which library are you using. The problem is probably that you need to explicitly specify the type constraints in one case and not in the other. I guess the example using `new ImmutableMap.Builder()` produces a warning about using raw types.

Answer (score 2):

`ImmutableMap.builder` is generic. You need to provide arguments to it. Otherwise it will infer `ImmutableMap.Builder<Object, Object>` as its return type.

`ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()` should do the trick.

First one is working because apparently you can assign raw type to paramtrized.

```
ImmutableMap v1 = ...;
ImmutableMap<String, String> v2 = v1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the original question, but if you are using Java 9 (or later) you can use Java's standard library [Map.of()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of--) to create an immutable map:

```
private static final Map<String, String> LOCALE_FOLDER_MAP = Map.of("a", "b");
```